# Running Jarsigner utility on android system

Tags: android, verification, jarsigner

I want to create a security app and want to check if a downloaded application is not tampered with,
I found a solution to verify app using the `jarsigner` utility but can i do it programatically?

I have seen we can add binaries and use it programatically, can i do that in this scenario? HOW??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android check if the APK signature verifies at install time, you don't have to do it manually. However, it doesn't necessarily mean that signature is *your* signature, anyone can re-sign an APK. And with the recent so called 'MasterKey' exploits, APKs can be modified without invalidating the signature (as far as Android is concerned). So, if you want to make sure you are getting the same binary you expect, calculate its SHA1, etc. hash and compare to what you are expecting. You can also check whether the signing certificate is your own. This will give you the binary certificate:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
byte[] certDer = pm.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures[0];
```

Comment: but will comparing the SHA1 of such applications with the database on server that holds records of apps wid diff versions and their hash 'll do good????

Comment: You need to keep separate hashes for each version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a maven plugin for this.you can use this for signing your APK file.https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/SigningAPKWithMavenJarsigner

Comment: The question is not about how to sign an apk, but rather about how to verify a signature, **with code running on the device itself**.